# How to better structure error handling in ajax rich webapps

Tags: ajax, error-handling

I am creating a webapp which makes a lot of ajax requests to server. I want to know the best practices to provide structure to error handling in ajax. I am using PHP for server side handling.

I am using a tooltip plugin which will display various error messages to user. Also I have setup various error codes on server side. Now how should I handle the error messages.

- Should I send the error messages as ajax response (this should be a no-no as the data exchange between server & client should be minimal)
- Should I just send the error code in response - this way i will have to handle the error display on client side, my error messages will reside in javascript

Any tips on how can I better handle the situation over here? Basically I would like the separate the content (messages) from behavior (javascript).